# A guy having big belly should do cardio or weight training? if both, than in what order?

Tags: weight-loss, cardio

The guy do not want to get 6 packs abs or attrative musclular body. He just want to shed some weight to lead healthy , disease free life.

Comment: If all you want is to lose weight ... do all cardio!

Comment: First in a workout, or first as in six months worth? What kind of cardio or weight training are you choosing between? What's your current fitness ability? We need further detail to be helpful.